# Since when are we getting group account while fetching sharepoint users

Tags: sharepoint, office365

We are trying to get all the users/members from a modern SharePoint site using csom code(below) and in doing so we are also getting the office 365 group id which is created for modern site. Is this introduced recently or is this an existing behavior?

RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = clientContext.Web.RoleAssignments;
 clientContext.Load(roleAssignments, ra => ra.Include(inc => inc.Member, inc => inc.RoleDefinitionBindings));

Answer (score 0):

The `Member` property of a `RoleAssignment` has always held both Users and Groups, long before the existing of O365 and SharePoint in the cloud.

Here are a few very old references and threads citing the usage of groups in SharePoint RoleAssignments from more than 10 years ago, including a reference from SharePoint 2007:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7d207fe0-0209-4f15-9b86-e6bf596edaea/determine-sproleassignment-type?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy
- https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/SPRoleAssignment/-/php-sproleassignment-class-examples.html
- https://books.google.com/books?id=YbFvTChU9MAC&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=sproleassignment+member+group&source=bl&ots=vqgNzaAgs9&sig=ACfU3U1wqj_xkD7LGOiFAzKgtFkF2MF7NQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ4aS52vLnAhU3mHIEHYT2CZAQ6AEwCHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=sproleassignment%20member%20group&f=false